# Any new version of tf.placeholder?

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder, tensorflow2.0

I have a problem using `tf.placeholder`, as it has been removed in the new version of TensorFlow, 2.0.

What should I do now to use this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just apply data directly as input to the layer. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.normal(size=(3, 2))
astensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train)
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(astensor)
print(logits.numpy())
# [[ 0.21247671  1.97068912]
#  [-0.17184766 -1.61471399]
#  [-0.03291694 -0.71419362]]
```

The `TF1.x` equivalent of the code above would be:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_ = np.random.normal(size=(3, 2))
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x:input_}))
# [[-0.17604277  1.8991518 ]
#  [-1.5802367  -0.7124136 ]
#  [-0.5170298   3.2034855 ]]
```